# Dirichlet Process Concentration Parameter - collapse at zero

Tags: bayesian, computational-statistics, dirichlet-process

**Background**
I've implemented the blocked gibbs sampler for sampling from the posterior of a dirichlet process mixture model as described on p.552 of [Bayesian Data Analysis](https://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/), placing a Gamma prior on the concentration parameter $\alpha$.

When using the Dirichlet Process to estimate the mixture membership of a sample consisting of three different Poisson distributions (See simulation [document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CRN2zeCF5Fi2lqiahx9rnfnwDoCEFioK) and [code](https://github.com/apeterson91/BEFcluster/blob/dad230313386839600fd63868022e79d928d5da7/src/rcppeigen_hello_world.cpp) for full details ), the Dirichlet Process is able to nearly perfectly estimate cluster membership, but estimates P($\alpha$ =0)=1. That is, all the MCMC samples for $\alpha$ are 0.

I'm looking for perspectives to help me work through whether $P(\alpha=0)=1$  offers any problems for the validity of any inference made from this (or future, similarly constructed) model(s).

**Question**
Do these model results suggest any problems since $\alpha = 0$ is on the boundary of the parameter space?

Comment: Your implementation probably has a bug, as $P(\alpha=0)=0$ in the prior implies  $P(\alpha=0|\text{data})=0$ in the posterior.